# A disappearing div if not surrounded in a <div style="display:block;">...</div> - Why is that?

Tags: html, css

I have a ul with li's which in turn contains some divs. You could see it on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtKra/

Here is the ul structure:

```
<ul class="categoryListing">

<li class="category">
    <div class="hoverMenu">
        <a class="edit">
            <img class="hoverButton editIcon" src="${baseRef}/images/editpencil.png"/>
        </a>
        <a class="delete">
            <img class="hoverButton deleteIcon" src="${baseRef}/images/deleteredicon.png"/>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div style="width:20px; height:20px; background-color:red; position:relative; top:2px; margin:0; padding:0; float:left; border-radius:2px; text-align:center;"><div class="arrow-down"></div></div>
    <div style="width:185px; margin:0; padding:0; float:right; z-index:100; display:visible;">Here is the name of the category that you want to use</div>
    <!--DISAPPEARING DIV-->


</li>

<li class="category">
    <div class="hoverMenu">
        <a class="edit">
            <img class="hoverButton editIcon" src="${baseRef}/images/editpencil.png"/>
        </a>
        <a class="delete">
            <img class="hoverButton deleteIcon" src="${baseRef}/images/deleteredicon.png"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative; display:block">
        <div style="width:20px; height:20px; background-color:yellow; position:relative; top:2px; margin:0; padding:0; float:left; border-radius:2px; text-align:center;">&#9660;</div>
        <div style="width:185px; margin:0; padding:0; float:right;">Here is the name of the category that you want to use</div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

The thing is that the div with the content just disappears if it's not within an outer div which 
has style set to display:block. Is there a reason for that happening??

I'm using the inline style only for testing out the layout...the styles for the ul and li, can be seen on the above url if you wish. But am I missing some CSS thing that is preventing the div from showing? Why is that?

Comment: I don't get it, if I take out the `display: block;`, it looks just fine (in Firefox 5), http://jsfiddle.net/rtKra/1/.  What browser did you test this in?

Comment: What browser are you having trouble with? When I view your JSFiddle, it looks fine to me (both "Here is the category" divs appear fine. The only obvious error I can see in your code is a `display:visible` style, which is incorrect (`visible` is a value for the `visibility` property, not the `display` property, but that shouldn't be having any effect, as it should be visible anyway).

Comment: @mu, @spudley, @Keoki: Testing in chrome...and it works in FF!!! Should I just go ahead and add a display:block to 'patch it up'?? My other divs with a similar structure seem to be working fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce it here (I've only got Firefox on this machine), but I think I can guess what the problem is:

The problem is likely to be because the `<div>` is contained within an `<li>`, and because the `<div>` is styled by default as `display:block;`, whereas the `<li>` is styled by default as `display:list-item;`.

`display:list-item` works similarly to `display:inline` in that it cannot contain block elements. The rules say you cannot have a `block` element inside an `inline` element. It doesn't make sense.

Obviously people do this all the time, and the browsers have to be able to cope with it, but it is an error, and some browsers will cope better than others.

The solution to the problem is to style the `<li>` as `display:inline-block;`.

`inline-block` is a way of styling the display property such that the element remains inline in relation to the other elements around it, but can contain block type contents.

So add this CSS and you should be fine:

```
li.category { display:inline-block; }
```

Hope that helps. As I say, I can't test it here, but please let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: Absolutely correct :) I just +1-ed my CSS wisdom (and the post :) It works just fine! Thanks a ton!

Comment: `<li>`s by default are styled `display:list-item`, not `display:inline`.

Comment: @Alohci - you're right, thanks. I'll fix the answer. Same end result though  :)